# Column separation in math mode

Tags: math-mode, matrices

I'm trying to put the following three equations into a matrix:

```
$$x_1 + 2x_2 = 7\\
-2x_1 + 5x_2 = 4\\
-5x_1 + 6x_2 = -3$$
```

When I use the following `bmatrix`:

```
$$\begin{bmatrix}1\;2\;7\\-2\;5\;4\\-5\;6\;-3\end{bmatrix}$$
```

the resulting matrix is a mess, with no real column separation. Is there a way to specify columns in math mode? I know about presetting column separation widths, but I would rather it be done automatically, rather than as a presetting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the LaTeX `tabular` and `array` environments, as well as in the matrix-like environments such as `matrix`, `pmatrix`, `bmatrix`, and `vmatrix`, the only widely recognized column separator character is `&`. If you replace all instances of `\;` with `&`, the resulting output will start to look much better.

To make the matrix at hand look *really good*, though, you may want to switch from using a `bmatrix` to a `bmatrix*` environment and impose right-alignment of the column contents. Plus, add a `\phantom{-}` directive to one of the cells in the middle column to balance the column widths.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools} % for 'bmatrix*' env.
\begin{document}
\[
\begin{bmatrix}1\;2\;7\\-2\;5\;4\\-5\;6\;-3\end{bmatrix}
\quad\text{vs.}\quad
\begin{bmatrix} 1&2&7\\-2&5&4\\-5&6&-3 \end{bmatrix}
\quad\text{vs.}\quad
\begin{bmatrix*}[r] 1&2&7\\-2&5&4\\-5&\phantom{-}6&-3 \end{bmatrix*}
\]
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

have a look --- https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Mathematics#Matrices_and_arrays

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}

\[
M=
  \begin{bmatrix}
    1 & 2 & 3  \\
    3 & 4 & 5  \\
    5 & 7 & -3
  \end{bmatrix}
\]

\end{document}
```

### OR

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\begin{document}

\[
M=
  \begin{bmatrix*}[r]
    1 & 2 & 3  \\
    3 & 4 & 5  \\
    5 & 7 & -3
  \end{bmatrix*}
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]